# How to reference a ruby class at the same level of another ruby class within a module?

Tags: ruby

For example:

```
module Example
  class A
    def initialize
      puts "A"
    end
  end

  class B
    def initialize
      ::A.new
    end
  end
end
```

Instead of:

```
module Example
  class A
    def initialize
      puts "A"
    end
  end

  class B
    def initialize
      Example::A.new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Write the question in the text, not in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There really isn't a nice way to reference a class at exactly the same level. However, knowing how Ruby's constants resolution works will cover you in pretty much most cases.

There are two scope gates: the keywords `module` and `class`. The search starts in the current scope. If the constant is not found there, the search continues up the tree to the previous scope. And so on until you reach the main scope.

Putting `::` in front of a constant references the main scope.

---

Following these rules, using `B#new` as an example:

```
Example::A.new
```

searches for `Example` in `B`'s scope. It doesn't find it there. It goes to `Example`'s scope and uses that `Example`.

```
::A.new
```

Starts from the main scope and searches for `A` there. It doesn't find one and therefore fails.

```
::Example::A.new
```

Starts from the main scope and searches for `Example` there. It finds it and searches for `A` in that scope. It finds it and uses that `A`

```
A.new
```

Starts from `B`'s scope. It doesn't find it there and moves up to `Example`'s scope. It finds `A` there and uses it.

Answer (score 3):

`B` can access `A` like this:

```
module Example
  class A
    def initialize
      puts "A"
    end
  end

  class B
    def initialize
      A.new
    end
  end
end
```

Using `::A` tells ruby to look for `A` in the top-level scope.